# What is the Linear Execution Model in Meteor?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, meteor

In the [Meteor Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp), it states:

> In Meteor, your server code runs in a single thread per request, not
>   in the asynchronous callback style typical of Node. We find the linear
>   execution model a better fit for the typical server code in a Meteor
>   application.

What is this linear execution model, when compared to Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js uses asynchronous event loops, which stops a function from blocking the entire server.

Meteor is build on top of [Node Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers), which are themselves built on top of the asynchronous event loop.

A Node 'fiber' is like a connection, or an instance of your app. Within each fiber, the code is synchronous (i.e. blocking). However, there can be **multiple simultaneous synchronous** Node Fibers (connections) running on the **same asynchronous event loop**.